# how to get the output of thread which is already joined

Tags: multithreading, perl

how to get the output of thread which is already joined.

I am writing a perl script in which i call a multi_thread subroutine from a .pm file to do multithread operations like create(),tid() and join() and returns thread objects to calling program.

and in the main script I want to get the output of thread sub1.
But i am hitting with an error **thread already joined at**...................

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use multithread;

sub sub1
{
 print "hello\n";
 return 1;
}

my @thread_obj=multi_thread(sub1);
my $res=$thread_obj[0]->join();
print "thread1 output : $res\n";
```

Comment: Maybe you have already joined thread in multithread module.

Comment: yes, but i want the output of that thread in .pl file as shown above

Comment: This question falls into same category with "How to read from closed file handle".

Comment: you mean its impossible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A joined thread is one that's complete, and has been 'merged' with the main program. It doesn't exist any more.

What you could *perhaps* do is use `Thread::Queue` and have your thread enqueue it's result - a queue persists until the program exist.

E.g.

```
use Thread::Queue;
my $result_q = Thread::Queue -> new();

sub sub1
{
    print "hello\n";
    $result_q -> enqueue ( 1 ); 
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can process your result queue with `dequeue` or more likely `dequeue_nb` to drain it entirely. But you can `enqueue` more complex data structures when combined with `Storable`.

Of course, the real answer would be - capture the output of the thread when you join, and store it somewhere. Like within your module, or wherever you do the *actual* join call.